# How to use the for loop in this situation

Tags: javascript

I have data like this:

```
data = [
         { 'name':'suresh', 'age':25}
         { 'name':'ramesh', 'age':35}
         { 'name':'raina', 'age':15}

      ]
```

I have tried like

```
  for(let ele in data){
     consolelog(ele)
   }
```

**Current Output**

```
 0
 1
 2
```

**Expected Output**

```
     { 'name':'suresh', 'age':25}
     { 'name':'ramesh', 'age':35}
     { 'name':'raina', 'age':15}
```

Comment: you can you [for-of loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) or `data.forEach(console.log)`

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the `of` keyword for looping arrays

```
 for(let ele of data){
    console.log(ele)
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because by doing this:

```js
for(let ele in data){
  consolelog(ele)
}
```

You're looping the properties of the array. An array is really just an object with the properties `0`, `1`, `2`, ...

There are several ways to loop an array. In my opinion the two most common are:

```js
// old-school...
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  console.log(data[i]);
}

// ... new-school (ES5+)
data.forEach(ele => console.log(ele));
```

Answer (score 1):

By your approach

```js
let data = [
         { 'name':'suresh', 'age':25},
         { 'name':'ramesh', 'age':35},
         { 'name':'raina', 'age':15}
      ];
      for(let ele in data){
    console.log(data[ele]);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code this work for me

`for (let ele in data) {
  console.log(data[ele])
}`